# Tooltip in Scatter

Tags: highcharts, tooltip, scatter

I having problem adding unix timestamp as extra point in tooltip.
My code is showing no graph. Help!
Here is part of my code:

My data array: $data[] = "[x:$valDE,y:$valDN,z:$datetime]";

And my javascript:

```
    var <?php echo $chart ?> = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter',
            renderTo: '<?php echo $container ?>',
            zoomType: '',
            marginLeft: 50,
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        title: {
            text: '<?php echo "$gps $location"; ?>',
            style: {
                fontSize: '<?php echo $sizeTitle ?>'
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Data is average pr. day - viewing <?php if($range == "All"){echo "ALL DATA";}else if($range == "1 YEAR"){echo "LAST YEAR";}else{ echo "last ".$range;} ?>',
            style: {
                fontSize: '<?php echo $sizeSubTitle ?>'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                enabled: true,
                text: 'EW',
                align: 'high'
            },
            min:-<?php echo $maxAxis ?>,
            max:<?php echo $maxAxis ?>,
            offset: <?php echo $offSetX ?>,
            tickInterval: <?php echo $tickInterval ?>
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'NS',
                align: 'high'
            },
            min:-<?php echo $maxAxis ?>,
            max:<?php echo $maxAxis ?>,
            offset:<?php echo $offSetY ?>,
            lineWidth:1,
            tickInterval: <?php echo $tickInterval ?>
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: <?php echo $legendX ?>,
            y: <?php echo $legendY ?>,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            borderWidth: 1,
            itemStyle: {
                fontSize: '<?php echo $legendSize ?>'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            scatter: {
                marker: {
                    radius: <?php echo $lineWidth ?>,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: false,
                            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                        }
                    },
                    symbol: "circle"
                },
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: 'EW: {this.x} mm<br>NS: {this.y} mm<br>Date: {this.point.z}'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            color: '#990000',
            name: '<?php echo $legFive ?>',
            data:[<?php echo join(${$da}, ',') ?>]
        },{
            color: '#ff0000',
            name: '<?php echo $legFour ?>',
            data:[<?php echo join(${$da4}, ',') ?>]
        },{
            color: '#ffcc33',
            name: '<?php echo $legThree ?>',
            data:[<?php echo join(${$da3}, ',') ?>]
        },{
            color: '#66ff66',
            name: '<?php echo $legTwo ?>',
            data:[<?php echo join(${$da2}, ',') ?>]
        },{
            color: '#3300ff',
            name: 'Last',
            data:[<?php echo join(${$da1}, ',') ?>]
        }]
    });
    <?php }//for ?>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See this example for how to go about it:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/fbMQf/

You need to supply the data as an object with key->value pairs, and call accordingly in your formatter.

```
see fiddle for code
```

Comment: [json_enconde](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) may be helpful to get proper JSON from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX timestamps should be multiply by 1000, and be sorted by x ascending. Could you attach your example series data: "echo join(${$da1}, ',')" ?

Comment: Examples: [0] => [x:-27.31,y:6.51,z:1363651200000]
    [1] => [x:-27.32,y:6.28,z:1363737600000]
    [2] => [x:-26.85,y:6.65,z:1363824000000]
    [3] => [x:-26.94,y:6.51,z:1363910400000]
    [4] => [x:-27.03,y:6.78,z:1363996800000]
    [5] => [x:-27.39,y:7.19,z:1364083200000] and multiplied with 1000: $datetime = $row['datetime']*1000; and also ASC in place: ORDER BY EventTime ASC";

Comment: If you have xAxis as datetime, x should have timestamp. Also it needs to be number, not string.

Comment: This is a scatter graph. It is working perfectly when im just have this array, without the extra z and without naming x and y in array. eks. $data[] = "[$dE,$dN]"; $dE is like x and $dN is y. Works! X isnt a datetime, just a number as y is. The problem is tooltip. I wont to add datetime as extra information to tooltip. Therfore i tried to expand the data array to $data[] = "[$dE, $dN, $datetime]" in hope that i could use $datetime as extra information in tooltip for each point in scatter. I have tried this.point without luck.